# How to send ether from one account to another in a smart contract deployed on testrpc

Tags: solidity, testnets, testrpc, testrpc-to-ropsten

I'm interested in writing a smart contract using solidity that sends ether from one account to another. What would the syntax be? If possible, could you point me to a solidity contract that sends ether from one party to another?

For example, say two parties enter into a smart contract, they both wager some ether on a coin flip. In the case of the coin flipping heads, the person who called heads should get the money both people wagered.